# What is a thematic way for a Horror Antagonist to wager with a PC?

Tags: horror, dont-rest-your-head

The PC's need to get some information from an information broker in a Horror game. (Think of it as an information demon.) The stakes are dire but not deadly. I want some way for them to compete/wager/gamble to get what they want,  but asking the player to "roll versus your poker skill" seems vapid.

I need a mechanic with a clear winner and loser, that allows for a build-up of tension without being silly, and would fit a dark horror setting. **It doesn't have to be a game, or cards.**

Bonus points if there is a way for the demon or player to cheat.

Comment: What are the consequences—if any—for losing the card game? Can the PCs beat the adventure *without* winning the card game?

Comment: I want to suggest Uno, but that only really works when its multiplayer and everyone else just played those pickup cards on you

Comment: The edit made it better, but it still seems more appropriate to a discussion forum than RPG.se. Though there are enough restrictions to make me wrong, possibly.

Comment: I’m afraid this is a (off topic) game recommendation question.  I’m not sure if board and card game SE takes shopping questions but if they do you might ask there.

Comment: B&CG doesn't take questions about having a game recommended, alas.

Comment: But I am not asking for a game recommendation in the sense of "is chess  better than AD&D".  I am asking for a story mechanic appropriate for the genre.  Aren't questions about story mechanics appropriate to this site?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if they don't have time for poker, how about Indian poker? The general structure is a little goofy what with the putting a card on your head, but the idea - bidding based only on what you know about your opponent's card - puts a lot of suspense on the line.

Maybe the card goes into your soul, and you can't look at your own soul. If you play with the Tarot deck (minus the Major Arcana) you can flavor the NPC's cards appropriately.

Not sure how you want to structure it. Gambling with chips and whoever goes bust or concedes first owes a big favor? Gambling with chips that themselves represent favors and you're trying to get them to bet the big important one?

There's an interesting twist to it you might want to borrow from the Korean reality TV bluffing/deduction game, The Genius. All Minor Arcana (kings, queens, knights, pages) have equal values and beat any number card, but if you ever fold when you have a Minor Arcana you've betrayed yourself and your opponent can demand an appropriate favor from you.